# Show the details from database in jcombobox in GUI

Tags: java, database, swing, awt, jcombobox

Fetch data from database and display in Jcombobox.
I need to only fetch one column values from daabase name(Combobox).
The Column in my database are id and Package, i have to fetch package values in jcombobox.

Table in database:  ID  | Package
                    1   | Dadar
                    2   | Matunga
                    3   | Colaba

```
 private void jComboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

       // ArrayList<Welcome> w = new ArrayList<Welcome>();
        List<alldetails> el;
alldetails all;
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement pst;
        ResultSet rs;
        String pack;

        try {
           Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
           con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ToursandTravel","root","root");

           String query=("select Package from COMBOBOX");
           Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

           rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next())
            {
               // System.out.println("Data "+rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
               // pack=rs.getString("Id");
                jCombo.addItem(rs.getString("Package"));

            }                

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }          

    }
```

I am not able to fetch the package column from the database in jcombobox.

Comment: Do any one has any solution for this?

Comment: *"am not able to fetch the package column from the database in jcombobox."* Is the problem fetching the data, or entering it into the combo box? 1st try populating the combo with hard coded data. General tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.